# Java WSDL client side with dynamic address

Tags: java, web-services, soap, soap-client, wsdl2java

Initially WSDL location was given using which I generated the server classes in the client side. Now the server side is deployed as a war file at a different port. We must be able to load wsdl from the new location without modifying the client side code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually pretty simple. Since I was new to web service I felt it to be an herculean task.
What I did was stored the new WSDL access URL inside a property file and then loaded the value into the project.